# custom config in rails (3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking to setup an alternate development config in rails3.

I have copied the development.rb file in config/environments to developmentck.rb

Also added a section to database.yml with the above name - but when I run the mongrel server using

```
rails s -c developmentck
```

It complains that the configuration developmentck does not exist.

Thanks in advance for any tips on what this noob is doing.

~chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be `-e` instead of `-c`